# CSS three column layout, liquid center, no left-margin!

Tags: css

I am all in favor of CSS based layouts, but this one I just can't figure out. With a table it is oh-so-easy:

```
<html>
<head><title>Three Column</title></head>
<body>
<p>Test</p>
<table style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; min-height: 300px;">
<tr>
<td style="border: 1px solid green;" colspan="3">Header</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid green; width: 150px;" rowspan="2">Left</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid yellow;">Content</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid blue; width: 200px;" rowspan="2">Right</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid fuchsia;">Additional stuff</td>
</tr>
<tr><td style="border: 1px solid green;" colspan="3">Footer</td></tr>
</body>
<html>
```

- Left is fixed width
- Right is fixed width
- Content is liquid
- Additional stuff sits beneath content

Now here is the important part: "Left" **may not exist**. Again this is easy with the table. Delete the column and "Content" expands. Beautiful.
I have looked through many examples (and "holy grails") of liquid and table less three-column CSS based layouts, but I have not found one which is not using some kind of margin-left for the middle column ("Content"). Any margin-left will suck once "Left" is gone as "Content" will just stay at it's place.

I'm just about to switch to old school table based layout for this problem, so I'm hoping someone has some idea - I don't care about excess markup, wrappers and the like, I would just like to know how to solve this with plain CSS. Btw: look at how easy equal height columns are...

Cheers

PS: No CSS3 please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
body {
width: 600px;
}
.left {
float: left;
width: 200px;
}
.center {
float: right;
width: 100%;
}
.right {
float: right;
width: 200px;
}
```

this should let the .center expand to the full width when left is removed

Comment: Wouldn't it be legal for a browser to make the center as wide as the whole window, requiring horizontal scrolling?  (I was under the impression "100%" means "the entire width of the parent element", not just whatever's left.)

Comment: Theoretically it should, but practically this doesn't work.

What you will get is .left floated to the left, 200px wide - next line a 100% (600px wide as defined by you) .center and in the next line a .right floated to the right. You do not get the columns floating next to each other.